# Routing in Web Api with different types of route values

Tags: c#, .net, routes, asp.net-web-api2

How will Route parameters look like, if the request link is like this:

**Cash/Users/{UserId}/Transactions?PartnerUserSessionKey={PartnerUserSessionKey}**

Something like this ?

```
[Route("cash/users/{userid}/transactions")]
        private void CreateCashTransaction(int userid,[FromUri] Transaction transaction, Someclass otherinfo) {}
```

Where Someclass is additional info which is not included in Url

Comment: What you want to do with `Someclass`? Is it null by default? How are you going to assign value to `otherinfo`. For me your question is unclear to me. Provide some input data and expected output

Comment: Someclass is part of request which is not included in url. I need to use this info for sending right responce

Comment: Input includes userid, transaction partner session key.. these 2 come with url, and transaction id, transaction name which comes by json (not from url). I need to send some responce to this request. Example of url is [link](https://{yourhost}/{yourpath}/Cash/Users/7EPrUwhd/Transactions?PartnerUserSessionKey=kKHTmWCD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SomeClass needs to be the first param in the function.